# NiFi expression language dealing with special characters in JSON keys

Tags: json, escaping, apache-nifi

So I have some json in which the keys might be something like this:

```
{
    "name" : "John",
    "num:itparams:enterprise:2.0:content" : {
      "housing" : "5"
    },
    "num rooms": "12"
}
```

I get this json from an http request, and I need to use the evaluateJsonPath processor to create attributes from them.

name is easy, i just use $.name

But how would I access the other two? I imagine you would put them in quotes somehow to escape the special characters but just doing $."num:itparams:enterprise:2.0:content" doesnt work.

Comment: try `$['num:itparams:enterprise:2.0:content']['housing']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the bracket for the key-value which has the special characters such as

```
$.['num:itparams:enterprise:2.0:content'].housing
```

then it will give you the evaluated result `5`.